# Validating part of the model in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am trying to wrap my head around doing validation in a MVC scenario. I have my application setup so that it has a Data/Repository layer that uses Linq2SQL and creates objects in my domain model. I don't expose my Linq2SQL objects directly to the rest of my app however, for now, my domain model mostly looks like my database tables. I wanted to do this in case I wanted to drop Linq2SQL later.

Then I have a service layer that is called from my controllers to perform actions and grab my domain model from my Data layer.

I want to use a validation framework such as [xVal](http://xval.codeplex.com/). It seems common wisdom that your model should contain your validation rules. My question is how do you validate part of the model (or various states)? For instance, I have a User object that has username, password and other properties. I have a Login action where I'd like to make sure the Username and Password are provided. However, when I create a new user, I'd want more fields to be required. It seems weird to create a Login object in my model when I already have my User object.

Right now, my Login action is just taking a username and password parameter that are posted to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that validation is usual in the Model layer.  The problem is probably in your domain model --- you have an idea of a User that isn't valid until it has all that stuff in it.

Think instead of a User that can be anonymous, or can be filled in.  An easy way to think that out is to have User have an instance of a Credentials object; that's also a good place to track permissions etc.

Comment: This is an interesting way to look at it. Basically, it will show me where I need to pull out parts of my physical model into more of a logical model. This will make it easier to validate part. I'll see how this goes. Thanks!

Comment: yeah.  The thing to do is to think about the DOMAIN model.  Here you have in your "stories" a case where your session can be anonymous; the object model should represent that.  Another version would have a Session that has-a User that can be anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but I cannot think beyond your example.  A user object shouldn't have a login method.  What I do is have the following

```
public class User
{
  public bool ConfirmPassword(string password)
  {
    ... 
  }
}
```

Then a repository.  This finds the user by their userName, and then checks ConfirmPassword to see if it is correct, if not it returns null.

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
  ..other stuff..
  User GetByUserNameAndPassword(string userName, string password);
}
```

As for validation I usually have 2 ways of getting constraints.

```
//The constraint itself
public interface IConstraint
{
  string Name { get; }
  bool IsValid();
}

//A way to get constraints that are inexpensive to evaluate, such
//as Name != null etc.  This can be implemented as a service to provide
//custom constraints from an external source (such as rows in a DB)
//which then additionally checks "instance" if it implements the
//interface and adds its constraints to the result too.

//These are the kinds of constraints I evaluated in the GUI every
//time the object changes, so I can show a list of errors.
public interface IConstraintProvider
{
  IEnumerable<IConstraint> GetConstraints(object instance);
}

//Finally a way to get constraints that are expensive to evaluate, this
//includes checking invariants that might involve DB access.  These constraints
//(along with the cheap evaluation constraints) are all evaluated before
//my persistence service attempts to write the object's changes to the DB
public interface IPreSaveConstraintProvider
{
  IEnumerable<IConstraint> GetConstraints(object instance);
}
```

Comment: I don't have a Login method on my User object. I have a login method in my Service layer. My Repository returns IQueryable which the service layer uses (I know there is some debate about this)